# How to Create Data Frame using multiple text files using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, text

I Need to Create Data Frame Using Multiple text files, all the text files are in same directory

Text File Format, each text file contains data showed in image

[Text file format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNVvQ.png)

here I need to create DataFrame using these kind of multiple text files

Comment: Please post the text as text, not as an image.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/26415986/17489380 for a similar question and answer

Comment: You can load them in separate dataframe and use join, merge, or concat

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read multiple \*.txt files into Pandas Dataframe with filename as column header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26415906/read-multiple-txt-files-into-pandas-dataframe-with-filename-as-column-header)

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to remove the last line (Name: 45559, dtype: object) then you should be able to load txt file as a csv:

```
import pandas as pd
import os


txt_files_dir = '...'
files = os.listdir(txt_files_dir)
dfs_list = [pd.read_csv(file, sep='\s+') for file in files]
data_frame_result = pd.concat(dfs_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: no need keep last line, we need only first 20 rows  from text file

Comment: in that case you can preprocess the file beforehand to remove the last line and use the posted code snippet